# how to put spinner on socket io client sending and reciving data

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I working on big project, My client has not good internet speed so need to open-up spinner when send or receive data.
I tried for open spinner on "emit" and close that on "on" events but my problem here is some emits has do not return any thing.
I seeking for event ( for example "dataExchange" ) for open and close the preloader .

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if there is something like an dataExchange event but you could use acknowledgements
[What's Socket.IO sending and getting data (acknowledgements)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952092/whats-socket-io-sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements)