# How to send acknowledgment from Socket.IO server?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm having trouble sending acknowledgements from my socket.IO server. I've followed the documentation and added a function "fn" to my message handler function. Unfortunately fn is undefined. What's wrong with my code?

```
socket.on('search', function (searchParamsFromClient, fn) {
```

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417569/acknowledgment-for-socket-io-custom-event

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that's almost the same code I've wrote. My question is why is my callback, fn, undefined?

Comment: You should show the code you're using on "the other side" (the emitter of `search`), because that's where the callback is actually defined.

Comment: fn is the callback function. you have to define one!

Comment: @robertklep Thank you. You're right, I had to add a callback to the emitter-call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function 'fn' needs to be defined on the other side of the socket, i.e., the client.

**Server**:

```
socket.on('search', function (searchParamsFromClient, ack) {
  // do something with searchParamsFromClient
  ack();
}
```

**Client**:

```
socket.emit('search', searchPayload, function() {
  // acknowledgement
  // This function is what gets called as ack()
});
```

Comment: Simple explanation and easy to understand. Thanks !