# IOAcknowledge method is NOT working for SocketIO in Android?

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

I am using **socketio.jar** to establish the connection between **Client** and **Server**.

I.e. from my Android device(Client) to a Node server.

As I am successfully able to connect, send and receive messages to that server.

The problem is why I am **NOT** getting any **Acknowledgement** from socket after emitting message to the server. There is a callBack Interface **IOAcknowledge** as parameter, that never works/invokes for me.

```html
 socket.emit( "sendMessage", new IOAcknowledge() {

 @Override
 public void ack(Object... arg0) {

  System.out.println("sendMessage IOAcknowledge" + arg0.toString());
 }

 }, "Hi!! how are you");
```

Does anyone know the solution when or how that **IOAcknowledge** will work?

**EDIT :**
Docs link of socket library which i am using.

[Official](http://s01.de/hgexport/socket.io-java-client)
 and 
[Github](http://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client)

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that you forgot to invoke the callback on the server-side code:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('sendMessage', function (data, callback) {
       console.log('Message received:', data); 
       callback('Message successfully delivered to server!');
   });
});
```

For more information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417569/acknowledgment-for-socket-io-custom-event) thread or [docs](http://socket.io/docs/)

**EDIT:**

The problem also is that `Ack` implementation should come as ***last*** parameter of `emit` function, so your Java code should look like this:

```
socket.emit("sendMessage", "Hi!! how are you", new Ack() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        System.out.println("sendMessage IOAcknowledge" + args.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for approaching @rom4ek. we are getting an error when we integrated your kind of code.. that will be mentioned below by my mate.

Comment: callback('Message successfully delivered to server!');

         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
I have implemented this on server. But I am getting the above error

Comment: the socket.io library which i have used that have same sequence of parameters which i have posted. NOT according to your sequence.

Comment: u can check the official docs http://s01.de/hgexport/socket.io-java-client/ 
,  
https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

Comment: I guess you probably use different version in server and client side. You should try the newest one I think, check https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java and http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Comment: yeah in new newest library they have changed so many things.. if it is the only the option.. i will go through the latest version only..

Comment: Yes, I've changed answer also to the new version of  acknowledge interface - `Ack`.

Comment: so any suggestions/solution for my current socket version? becoz i asked question according to that version only.

Comment: No, I can't give you any suggestions, cause I don't know exactly, which versions do you use for client and server sides. But in my opinion you're using different versions on backend and client side, so make sure they are compatible with each other.