# Extract callback function from payload

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, arduino

1. I am using Node.js for emitting event to socket via `socket.emit(eventName[, ...args][, ack]).`
2. On client side, an Arduino, I'm using the SocketIoClient.h library (link: https://github.com/timum-viw/socket.io-client).

So the server is sending an event and a callback function as

```
socket.emit("event",function(x){
   console.log(x);
})
```

which is received on the client side in payload field as

```
clientSocket.on("event",event);
void event(const char * payload, size_t length);
```

How can I call this callback function from the client side, which is supposed to be present in the payload?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to use the acknowledgement mechanism offered by Socket.IO (I inferred this from the tags of your question).

For more details, refer to

- https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack
- [Acknowledgment for socket.io custom event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417569/acknowledgment-for-socket-io-custom-event)

This mechanism is specific to the Socket.IO library and therefore can't be used if you are not using it on both the client and the server sides.

As an alternative, I would suggest to dedicate a specific event to the acknowledgement you wish to have. In other words, when your client receives your event "event", it will send a "received" event to the server as acknowledgement along with the data your callback should be called with.

For instance on your server you would have:

```
socket.on("received", function (x) {
    console.log(x); //Will display "Yay! Got it!"
});
socket.emit("event");
```

and on the client something like

```
socket.on("event", function () {
    socket.emit("received", "Yay! Got it!");
});
```

(I'm not familiar with the C library you use but the point is the underlying logic).

Comment: yeah, I had a thought of this.But, i have already written my server codes.Now i have to change them. I'm gonna wait for some more answers.
thank you @Bret.e